# System.Web.HttpException: The file '/StudentPortal3G/Home.mvc.aspx' does not exist

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

Getting this error, everytime my home/INdex loads in my MVC3 app on Server 2008.

System.Web.HttpException: The file '/StudentPortal3G/Home.mvc.aspx' does not exist.

Tried all of this:

```
  routes.MapRoute(
                "Default",                                              // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}",                           // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }  // Parameter defaults
            );

            routes.MapRoute(
                "Default2",                                              // Route name             
                "{controller}.aspx/{action}/{id}",                      // URL with parameters             
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }  // Parameter defaults         ); 
            );
            routes.MapRoute(
                "Default3",                                             // Route name             
                "{controller}.mvc.aspx/{action}/{id}",                  // URL with parameters             
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }  // Parameter defaults         ); 
            );
```

Views\Home\Index.aspx exists.

IIS7 is not supposed to need the .* handler.
Do I need to set the aspx handler to not check existance of file? But the file exists?
If this is the answer, how do I set it on iis7, I wasn't able to find that to try it.

Isn't there a way to do it in the handlers section of the web.config?
Again I found a few hint's but I'm not quite getting it.

Thanks,

Cal-

Answer (score 0):

Did you add appropriate Views? In this case, you should have Views\StudentPortal3G\ (assuming that StudentPortal3G is a Controller) directory with Home.aspx inside and it maps to /StudentPortal3G/Home

Why are you trying to load Home.mvc.aspx at all is beyond me. I'd suggest you fire up [RouteDebug](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx) to see which rules you are missing...

Comment: StudentPortl3g is my app, Home should point to \Home\Index.aspx, right?

Comment: Yes. In order for it to work you need to have HomeController that has Index action. In Views directory you need to have Home directory with Index.aspx. If you got this wrong create a new MVC3 project and see how it looks there.

Comment: Create a NEW MVC3 project and trace your changes from there. You're missing something so simple, I can't pinpoint it like this :)